# Convert ECC Public key's Bignum to JWK X, Y Coordinates

Tags: openssl, elliptic-curve, bignum, jose4j, jwk

I have created public and private keys in OpenSSL using EC_Key and have x, y and d components in BigNum format.

Now I want to convert these Bignum values to Base64URLEncoded values as per JWK standards.

e.g.

```
{
 "kty":"EC",
 "crv":"P-256",
 "x":"MKBCTNIcKUSDii11ySs3526iDZ8AiTo7Tu6KPAqv7D4",
 "y":"4Etl6SRW2YiLUrN5vfvVHuhp7x8PxltmWWlbbM4IFyM",
 "use":"enc",
 "kid":"1"
}
```

Currently `x coordinate` is `76638B4D8040018F834AE6D6540B20E1CA95F6A8C61BE6118062918904B5C5A7`

While using OpenSSL and JSONKit in ObjC as

```
if (!bigNum) return nil;

/* converting from BIGNUM to binary */
int len = BN_num_bytes(bigNum);
unsigned char *buf = NULL;
buf = (unsigned char *) OPENSSL_malloc (len);
len = BN_bn2bin(bigNum, buf);
NSData *pubData =  [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:len freeWhenDone:YES];


NSString *base64EncodedString = [pubData base64EncodedString];
return [base64EncodedString stringWithBase64URLEncoding];
```

On converting it, it is giving `Base64URL encoded string` as

`x:dmOLTYBAAY-DSubWVAsg4cqV9qjGG-YRgGKRiQS1xac`

But while decoding the same x coordinate on server using Jose4J is returning it as:

`53548795424402895049922051400723229099982122334687022963594437126482323424679`

which is similar to available on website:
http://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php

From this is is indicated that it is decimal representation of BigInt

i.e.

1. Convert BigInt to Decimal
2. Decimal to ASCII String
3. and then to Base64 url encoding.

But while applying this process, server is not accepting the JWK param in JOSE4J library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but I *think* it would just be `BN_bn2bin()` for the x and y values, then convert the resulting data into base64url. RFC 7517 Appendix A says that JWKs need the big-endian values for x and y (and d if a private key), which is what BN_bn2bin is documented to give you.

Note that base64url is slightly different than regular base64; look at RFC 7515 Appendix C for note on how to use regular base64 routines then convert the result to base64URL.

Comment: This is specified more completely, and normatively, in RFC7518 6.2.1 by reference to SEC1 2.3.5, which specifies big-endian unsigned with **fixed size** based on the underlying (i.e. coordinate) field, with leading zero bytes if necessary. `BN_bn2bin` returns only the 'significant' bits/bytes, with variable size, so must be left-padded if necessary _before_ base64ing. Private 'd' is similarly fixed-size but based on the curve (group) order not the underlying field; these are the same for currently standardized curves but not for some other possible curves.